# Expression bodied member equivalent

Tags: c#, c#-8.0, expression-bodied-members

I'm just learning expression bodied members for class properties, and the basics are easy enough, but I'm trying to determine if the following `getter` could even be written as an expression bodied member - not for performance gain or anything, simply as a learning exercise:

```
public static List<Block> AllBlocks
{
    get
    {
        List<Block> allBlocks = new List<Block>(goalBlocks.Count +
                                pathBlocks.Count +
                                boardBlocks.Count);
        allBlocks.AddRange(goalBlocks);
        allBlocks.AddRange(pathBlocks);
        allBlocks.AddRange(boardBlocks);

        return allBlocks;
    }
}
```

As far as I can tell it cannot because it declares a new variable.  I've tried several ways of writing it like other FBM properties, and even went out on a limb and tried writing it in similar styles to a `Parallel.For` and `Parallel.ForEach` loop which I didn't expect to work, but figured I'd give it a try.

Comment: Well you could use `new[] { goalBlocks, pathBlocks, boardBlocks}.SelectMany(x => x).ToList()` which would achieve the same result, but slightly less efficiently...

Comment: There's a data dependency, so don't use any parallel processing. It will only add unnecessary overhead.

Comment: @JHBonarius - thanks.  I'm not actually using parallel processing, was just explaining one of the styles I was attempting to mimic for the `getter`.

Answer (score 4):

You could move away from declaring a new list inside your getter and rewrite as a simple union expression:

```
public static List<Block> AllBlocks =>
  goalBlocks.Union(pathBlocks).Union(boardBlocks).ToList();
```

Or if you don't explicitly need a list:

```
public static IEnumerable<Block> AllBlocks =>
  goalBlocks.Union(pathBlocks).Union(boardBlocks);
```

As pointed out below, `.Union()` will remove duplicates. If you don't intend for this to happen then you could use `.Concat()` instead.

```
public static IEnumerable<Block> AllBlocks =>
  goalBlocks.Concat(pathBlocks).Concat(boardBlocks);
```

Comment: I would use `Concat`... But the question is if he/she/they can or want to use Linq at all..

Comment: I think you meant to use `.Concat`. `Union` will remove duplicates, so would not be equivalent to the example.